How to share WiFi internet through ethernet using connman
How can I share internet from one computer to another using ethernet? Both use Linux. The one with WiFi access has an Artix installation with openrc and connman.
I think this is just a connman configuration but I have tried solutions on internet and it hasn't worked.

First, I tried enable tethering, adding ethernet to the configuration file in /etc/connman/main.conf.
This works the best. It creates a "network" and let the other computer connect to it, without global internet connection, but it connects and has an IP (a static ip). I can even ping the other computer. But not reach internet connection.

I also tried lnxrouter, I installed dnmasq for it to work and apparently it does something it shows a PID and then says "Setting up completed, ... should be working". But it doesn't, I can't even connect (I think it was made for debian based distros only).


